# How to extract exact words from a string using Python and re?

Tags: python, string, match, cpu-word, findall

The data sample is:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'Strings':['i xxx iwantto iii i xxx i',
                           'and you xxx and x you xxxxxx and you and you']})
b=['i','and you']
```

There are two words (phases) in b. I want to find them in a. I want to find the exact words, instead of substrings. So, I want the result to be:

```
['i' ,'i' ,'i']
['and you',' and you ',' and you']
```

I need to count how many times these words occur in a string. So I do not really need the above lists. I put it here because I want to show I want to find the exact words in the strings. Here is my try:

```
s='r\'^'+b[0]+' | '+b[0]+' | '+b[0]+'$\''
len(re.findall(s,a.loc[0,'Strings']))
```

I hope `s` can find the words in the beginning, in the middle and at the end. I have a big `a` and `b`. So I cannot just use the real string in here. But the result is:

```
len(re.findall(s,a.loc[0,'Strings']))
Out[110]: 1
re.findall(s,a.loc[0,'Strings'])
Out[111]: [' i ']
```

Looks like only the middle one is matched and found. I am not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: Your regular expression contains spaces which must be matched (but aren't there for most occurrences), try `\b` instead.

Comment: Cool. It works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'Strings':['i xxx iwantto iii i xxx i',
                           'and you xxx and x you xxxxxx and you and you']})
print(a.Strings.str.findall('i |and you'))
```

Output

```
0                   [i , i , i ]
1    [and you, and you, and you]
Name: Strings, dtype: object
```

---

```
print(a.Strings.str.findall('{} |{}'.format(*b)))
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is now what I want. I have a big list b and dataframe a. So I have to use the way in my question to construct a pattern as I do not know all the words that needs to be matched.